# Is Apache Curator try to reconnect until zk restart when zk clash?

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

My project depend on Apache Curator. I start zk and project, and then kill zk server, Is Apache Curator try to reconnect until zk restart ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Apache Curator will continue to attempt connections in the background as needed. Curator completely manages the ZooKeeper connection for you (NOTE: I'm the main author of Curator).